# Determinant of the symbolic matrix is giving very large expression

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I have a symbolic matrix of size 16  by 16. I tried to get the determinant of this symbolic matrix, but it turned out to be a very large expression. How to make this expression concise so that it makes some sense to analyze it. currently, I am having value for L, I changed the value of L from 1 to 4, now also I am getting the same thing. How to fix this?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
L = 1;
z[1] = L/3;
z[2] = L/2;
z[3] = 0.75*L;

W[1] = a[1]*Sin[b*x] + a[2]*Cos[b*x] + a[3]*Sinh[b*x] + a[4]*Cosh[b*x];
W[2] = a[5]*Sin[b*(x - z[1])] + a[6]*Cos[b*(x - z[1])] + 
   a[7]*Sinh[b*(x - z[1])] + a[8]*Cosh[b*(x - z[1])];
W[3] = a[9]*Sin[b*(x - z[2])] + a[10]*Cos[b*(x - z[2])] + 
   a[11]*Sinh[b*(x - z[2])] + a[12]*Cosh[b*(x - z[2])];
W[4] = a[13]*Sin[b*(x - z[3])] + a[14]*Cos[b*(x - z[3])] + 
   a[15]*Sinh[b*(x - z[3])] + a[16]*Cosh[b*(x - z[3])];
w = Piecewise[{{W[1], x <= z[1]}, {W[2], z[1] <= x <= z[2]}, {W[3], 
     z[2] <= x <= z[3]}, {W[4], x >= z[3]}}];


boundary[i_, j_] := 
 Module[ {bc}, 
  bc1 = {W[i] /. {x -> 0}, (D[W[i], {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 0}, (D[
       W[j], {x, 2}]) /. {x -> L}, ((D[W[j], {x, 3}]) /. {x -> L})}; 
  bc = bc1]

countinuity[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{eq}, 
  eq1 = {((W[i] /. x -> z[i]) - (W[j] /. 
        x -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x}]) /. 
        x -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x}]) /. 
        x -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x, 2}]) /. 
         x -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x, 2}]) /. x -> z[i])) + (Kr[
         i]*(D[W[i], {x, 1}]) /. (x -> z[i])), (((D[W[i], {x, 3}]) /. 
         x -> z[i]) - ((D[W[j], {x, 3}]) /. x -> z[i])) + (Kt[i]*
        W[i] /. x -> z[i])}; eq = eq1 ]

e1 = boundary[1, 4];
e2 = countinuity[1, 2] /. Kr[1] -> 0;
e3 = countinuity[2, 3] /. Kr[2] -> 0;
e4 = countinuity[3, 4] /. Kt[3] -> 0;   
eq = Flatten[{e1, e2, e3, e4}];
var = Table[a[i], {i, 1, Length[eq]}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
P = Det[R]
```

Comment: General hint: make the matrix numerical. That is, make the entries numerical, and **then** take the determinant. This is assuming that you tried `FullSimplfy[]` first and it didn't simplify enough.

Comment: I tried that, not working. and I am not using full simplify

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error message? Please explain because if it does not simplify, it may very well be because it can't be simplified symbolically.

Comment: I just have to give some values for kt and kr and take the det of the matrix find the roots

Comment: What you are requesting, a concide form of the determinant of a particular matrix, might simply not exist (for sufficiently sensible definitions of "concise").

Comment: I changed `z[3]` to be an exact value. After which: `In[79]:= Timing[det = Det[R];]

Out[79]= {249.703, Null}

In[80]:= LeafCount[det]

Out[80]= 56454

In[100]:= Timing[detS = Simplify[det];]

Out[100]= {129.391, Null}

In[101]:= LeafCount[detS]

Out[101]= 3841` So it's not dreadful in size at this point.

Answer (score 1):

There is something peculiar going on with determinant evaluation because `P[[6]]` to `P[[10]]` are **reciprocals**, while `R` has only simple polynomial matrix entries.

Still, the situation can be handled. Try the following code:

```
rulea = {1.->1, -1.->-1, 1/6.->f16, 1/4.->f14, 1/3.->f13};
ruleb = {
  Cos[b f16] -> c16, Cosh[b f16] -> ch16,
  Sin[b f16] -> s16, Sinh[b f16] -> sh16,
  Cos[b f14] -> c14, Cosh[b f14] -> ch14,
  Sin[b f14] -> s14, Sinh[b f14] -> sh14,
  Cos[b f13] -> c13, Cosh[b f13] -> ch13,
  Sin[b f13] -> s13, Sinh[b f13] -> sh13};
R1 = (R /. rulea /. ruleb); P1 = Det[R1] // Factor;
rulec = {c16 -> Sqrt[1 - s16^2], ch16 -> Sqrt[1 + sh16^2],
   c14 -> Sqrt[1 - s14^2], ch14 -> Sqrt[1 + sh14^2],
   c13 -> Sqrt[1 - s13^2], ch13 -> Sqrt[1 + sh13^2]};
ruled = {Sqrt[1 - s16^2] -> c16, Sqrt[1 + sh16^2] -> ch16,
   Sqrt[1 - s14^2] -> c14, Sqrt[1 + sh14^2] -> ch14,
   Sqrt[1 - s13^2] -> c13, Sqrt[1 + sh13^2] -> ch13};
P2 = (P1 /. rulec)/(-16 b^17) // Factor;
P3 = P2 // Expand /. ruled;
```

The result `P1` is `8 b^17` multiplied by a polynomial with 1226 terms while `P3` has only 518 terms.

Comment: Do you think there is a problem in the determinant